# How to Hide Sliding div on Document Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slide up and down a div (`.nav`) by clicking on another div (`#toggleMenu`)

Now my problem is when I run the page the (`.nav`) div pops up very fast. I used the  `$(".nav").hide();` to hide the div but this is happening after loading the (`.nav`) very fast.

here is the code I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav").hide(); 
    $("#toggleMenu").click(function () {
        $('.nav').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

and the css style is as:

```
.nav {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 0px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `.nav` element flashes before it hides on page load.

You could add display:none to the `.nav` rule and skip the `$(".nav").hide();` CSS loads faster than JavaScript.

Just keep in mind that it doesn't fallback gracefully if anybody has JavaScript disabled.

Another option would be to use a smooth animation, like `slideUp()`, on document ready. That way your page won't look wonky while it loads.